# Classical treatment of light-matter interaction, why light state changing is ignored?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser-interaction

In a semiclassical treatment of light-matter interaction commonly we treat atomic target (atom, surface, molecule, etc) quantum mechanically and the light is considered as a classical wave function which is oscillating in space and in time. When electrons have a  small velocity compared to that of light, the light is considered just as a vibration of the electric field which exercise an electric force on electrons. For optical light  one can ignore the spatial dependency in the electric field due to the small size of atoms (some Angstroms), this is known as the dipole approximation. Hence, the laser field can be written as
$$E(t)=E_0\sin(\omega t)$$ ( for a continuous light)

But if we are interested to a pulsed light, simply we add an envelope to the previous expression in which the amplitude is not either a constant (sine square, gaussian or even trapezoidal).

Let's be more specific, if our target is the atomic hydrogen. To study  the response of hydrogen to the laser field, we must solve the following time-dependent Schrödinger equation

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(r,t)=H(t)\psi(r,t)$$
The hamiltonian is the total energy of the system atom interacting with laser (this Hamiltonian just represent the H-atom system exposed to the influence of an electric force which oscillates respect to time variable)

$$H=  -\frac{\nabla^2}{2}-\frac{1}{r}+rE_0\sin(\omega t)$$

In literature, there are many methods that deal with analytical and numerical solution of the TDSE. Now I am converging toward my specific question. Why in such treatment the response of field laser to the atom is ignored (i.e. inverse influence), is because the lasers are intense  and a lost of some photons (i.e. some energy) doesn't change the light state ? If we inverse the treatment, consider a quantum light and a classical atom (e.g. CTMC) this can give the same deductions or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical treatment of the light-matter interaction considers a very strong electromagnetic field, i.e. the field with very large number of photons, interacting with a single atom. On the one hand, this means that we neglect small changes in the number of photons - if we were interested in such changes, we couldn't treat the field as classical. On the other hand, a single atom cannot cause macroscopic changes in such a strong field.

The situation changes when we consider classical field interacting with lots of atoms. We may still ignore small changes on a photon level, but many atoms may cause a microscopic change in the field. In this case one *must* take into account changes in the field, as it is done indeed, e.g., [when treating lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_diode_rate_equations).

Comment: In the case of  atomic gas interacting with intense laser, the atomic density is negligible with respect to that of photons. That's why, the classical treatment of light is validated. Even in surface science, they use a classical treatment to study the photoelectric effect, by analyzing the spectrum of photoelectrons, in which they can extract the atomic composition and their concentration based on a spectroscopic data references. But in condensed matter, such treatment couldn't be trusted, why I don't know, have you some ideas about it ?

Comment: I think another part of it is also the weak coupling, which allows perturbative treatment. In condensed matter this is usually not the case: the coupling is string, whereas the light intensities are weak. Do you have specific type of problems in mind?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I don't have a concert problem in mind, I worked recently on neon atom in strong laser field and I had this misunderstanding of the validity of classic light consideration but thanks to you I grasped well this. Concerning the perturbative treatment, I did it to calculate angular distributions of ejected electrons but with low field intensity ( minimum coupling ).